# How to get the value from a dropdown in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to get the value that user selects from my dropdown.
I have

```
<select ng-model="item" ng-change="vm.getItem()">
  <option value="discount">Discount</option>
  <option value="{{::item}}"
          ng-repeat="item in vm.items"
          ng-bind="item.name"
  </option>
  </select>
```

In my controller

```
vm.getItem = function() {
    vm.pickedItem = //not sure what to do...
    //I need to get the select item 
    //please noted that the discount is a stand alone option value. I need to get     
    //that too if user selects it.
}
```

I don't want to use `ng-option` as it has some restriction that I don't need. I was hoping to get it from just regular `<option>` tag.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: What restrictions does ngOptions have? In fact, ngRepeat is limited in this case and with ngOptions it would be simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I would recommend you to use ngOptions*

Set up `select` element with proper model i.e. `vm.pickedItem` which can be directly used in controller, or you can pass it to your method like `vm.getItem(vm.pickedItem)`

```
<select ng-model="vm.pickedItem" ng-change="vm.getItem(vm.pickedItem )">
    <option value="discount">Discount</option>
    <option value="{{::item}}"
          ng-repeat="item in vm.items"
          ng-bind="item.name">
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vm.getItem = function() {
    var selectedItem = vm.item; 
    ////vm.item is the bound variable to the dropdown's ng-model directive
}
```

If you really wanted to use the ng-change event in this scenario, then on your "getItem" event, you should access the model bound to the dropdown's ng-model called "item" as seen in your html markup.

Answer (score 1):

you forgetting to alis your controller in your `select`

```
<select ng-model="vm.item" ng-change="vm.getItem()">
```

In controller

```
vm.getItem = function() {
    console.log(vm.item)
   or
   console.log(this.item)
}
```